# Non-exact match vlookup with specific critiera

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have to column of data (time A and time B) and I would like to find out for each data a in A if there is a value b in B that meets the criteria of b-a = +/−0.007. I am trying to use vlookup but I cannot specify the criteria of b-a = +/−0.007. Can I do this using vlookup or there is other ways to do it in excel? Many thanks in advance for help!

The data example is shown below.

```
+----------------+------------------+
| Time A         | Time B           |
+----------------+------------------+
| 0.000          | 0.000            |
| 1.001          | 1.001            |
| 1.852          | 1.852            |
| 2.725          | 2.729            |
| 3.356          | 3.359            |
| 4.061          | 4.070            |
| 4.423          | 4.431            |
| 4.634          | 4.642            |
| 4.750          | 4.637            |
| 5.390          | 5.398            |
| 5.788          | 5.788            |
| 6.515          | 6.522            |
| 7.010          | 7.010            |
| 7.672          | 7.500            |
| 8.017          | 7.900            |
| 8.073          | 8.200            |
+----------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this VBA solution:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 2 To 16
    For j = 2 To 16
        If Abs(Cells(j, 2) - Cells(i, 1)) < 0.007 Then
            Cells(i, 3) = j
        End If

    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

It in column C it outputs the matching row index from column B:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the value in B can match any value in A. For example, there is a possibility that the value in B4 marches the value in A3 or A5, not exactly A4.

Comment: Then in that case I'd recommend a VBA solution

Comment: Could you suggest what function shall I use? I only know a little bit about VBA...

Comment: np, glad I could help;)